# implementation of include preprocessor in c

Tags: c, preprocessor

I want to write a C program for implementing the `include` functionality of the preprocessor.

Example:

In header.h I have this code:

```
char *test (void);
```

And in program.c:

```
int x;
#include "header.h"
int
main (void)
{
    puts (test ());
}
```

The input is `program.c`.

The output must be :

```
int x;
char *test (void);
int
main (void)
{
    puts (test ());
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: where did you define test() ?

Comment: in header.h I defined test().

Comment: It should be fairly easy to implement a minimal preprocessor.  If you're curious, you can look at something like [mcpp](http://mcpp.sourceforge.net) on Sourceforge, or [Gnu cpplib](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cpplib.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to read the input file line by line. Check to see if the line starts with #include (with optional leading whitespace). If not, print the line you've read. If so, open the specified file instead, and run this same algorithm on it (to handle secondary #includes).

Comment: @AComputert Open a file, read it line by line, keeping track of comments and strings so you don't try to process the statement `printf("#include <stdio.h>\n");` or the comment `/* #include <notfoundhere.h> */`.  Or read it all into memory and scan through that; or use `mmap()` to make it available in memory.  Or ...

Answer (score 0):

you can run gcc -E "your source files", and then filter the line included "#",the left is your wanted, and the macros is replaced by its real forms.

for example:

```
gcc -E hello.c|sed '/# .,$/d' > a.c
```

a.c is your wanted file.

Answer (score 0):

when use gcc
**gcc -E -P program.c**

or
**cpp -P program.c**

when use Visual c
**cl /EP program.c**